# How to replace native promise in browser with bluebird library

Tags: javascript, promise, bluebird, babeljs

According to the documentation from babel-loader (https://github.com/babel/babel-loader), I have tried the following step:

1. Create a 'bootstrap.js' file
2. Add the following line in the file

   ```
   require('babel-runtime/core-js/promise').default = require('bluebird');
   ```
3. Import the file in my index.js

However, I am still not able to replace the native Promise with bluebird. The reason for doing this is because I do not want to import the Promise library for every file.

Comment: I think you misunderstand the purpose of the bootstrap.js file - from what I read, the bootstrap loads the rest of the app (requires it), but you require the bootstrap in index.js

Comment: I don't think that make any difference though. I tried putting it at my entry point in webpack forcing it to load first but still no luck in getting the native library replace.